# Are width/height required in an iframe?

Tags: html, css, iframe

I have a long discussion with one person i know. 
He insists on using iframes to embed YouTube videos as:

```
<iframe style=”width: 560px; height: 315px; border: none;” src=”http://www.youtube.com/embed/bla-bla-bla?rel=0″></iframe>
```

that does work for some videos but not for all.

Youtube provides the following code to embed:

```
<iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/bla-bla-bla?rel=0" height="315" width="560" allowfullscreen="" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

which obviously works fine.

I was trying to find in specification of `iframe` if `width` and `height` are required. And what happens when they are not provided. But could not quite find the information.

Can someone please help me and explain why the first variant does not work always, and one, as far as i understand, is better of with the second variant?

EDIT1:

so the right answer is below. I just want to comment how i got those wrong curly symbols. The guidelines of one WordPress-based site give users these code snippets. That particular web-site (or it's css; or wordpress in general) don't distinguish between curly and straight quotes, always showing curly. THus when user copy-paste the code - it does not work.

Comment: Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3333399/iframe-default-height

Comment: @Loris that does not quite answer my question. Even if default width/height is there, the iframe does not work without specifying them. Not that it shows only part of the content...

Comment: Your first example has curly quotes instead of straight quotes. Does it work better if you fix that? I would expect the two versions to work identically if the quotes are corrected.

Comment: if you mean `style='width: 560px; height: 315px; border: none;'` - no, that does not solve the issues of youtube iframe not displaying the video

Comment: The `src` attribute has curly quotes too - but it sounds like that probably is not the problem. You may as well fix them though.

Comment: @MichaelGeary bingo! that was it. I still can't understand how the second code (which uses curly brackets) works. Strange.

Comment: I don't see any curly brackets (do you mean like {}?) in the second example, nor curly quotes either.

Comment: @MichaelGeary Sorry, i meant curly quotes ('' instead of "") in src.

Comment: Excellent - I'm glad that turned out to be it. I added it as an answer, along with a suggestion to use the HTML validation service to help catch problems like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per our discussion in the comments, the problem was caused by the curly quotes in the first example:

```
<iframe style=”width: 560px; height: 315px; border: none;”
    src=”http://www.youtube.com/embed/bla-bla-bla?rel=0″></iframe>
```

Changing to straight quotes fixed it:

```
<iframe style="width: 560px; height: 315px; border: none;"
    src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/bla-bla-bla?rel=0"></iframe>
```

It's helpful to validate your HTML using the [W3C Validation Service](http://validator.w3.org/). That would catch this error and many others.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that youtube accesses the height and width properties using window.frameElement

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.frameElement

They probably do this to adjust the video quality or something.

Those will not be present if you set the width and height using css, and they may encounter an error in their code and not show the video.

So the answer is, no those attributes are not requried, however in this scenario they seem to be.

I can only tell you for sure if you have an example.

Comment: thanks for explanation. Here is an example: `<iframe style='width: 560px; height: 315px; border: none;' src=”http://www.youtube.com/embed/k0rHak6aJl8?rel=0″></iframe>`

Comment: as it turned out it has to do with curly brackets.

Comment: oh, well... sometimes the most trivial explanations hide in plain sight :D